# Why do pieces of code in quotations become inline-blocks?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

I noticed that here on the meta site (not on the main site or anywhere else) inline runs of code get `display: inline-block`.

So if I type

```
> This is some `inline code
> with a return in it`, see?
```

I get this:

> This is some `inline code
>   with a return in it`, see?

Why is that?

This happens only inside quoted content (in lines starting with >); the same backticked code outside of a quotation works fine.

Note: in case the behaviour changes in the future, here is a screenshot of what I see now:

[image: screenshot from meta.stackoverflow]

and this is what the same looks like on any other site (this is from meta.stackexchange, if you must know):

[image: screenshot from meta.stackexchange]

Comment: Those are not quotation marks, they are backticks that indicate inline code. (or grave accent, outside of this site).

Comment: @TylerH No, I meant in blockquotes. The same backticked code in  a plain paragraph works as expected. It's only when preceding the lines by > signs that the issue begins.

Comment: @TylerH "why" aside, `blockquote code` does get its own special `display: inline-block;` property in the CSS, not applied to `<code>` on its own.

Comment: @PaulRoub Yes, and only here. Sounds like someone's been experimenting with the stylesheet a bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fixed in the next build (should be deployed soon-ish). Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Looks like soon-ish just happened; I'm seeing the fixed version.

Comment: Same here. Was a quick build!